# Polymorphic many-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent, polymorphism

I couldn't get  related models in many-to-many polymorphic relation saved into database.

```
$photo = Photo::find(1);
$photo->articles()->attach(2);
```

something like this wouldn't work and gives

> error: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::articles()'

How to do it the right way?

Models

```
class Tag extends Eloquent
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Article', 'taggable');
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Photo', 'taggable');
    }
}
class Article extends Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}

class Photo extends Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you where you saw `morphedByMany`?

Comment: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_morphedByMany

Comment: http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/visualizing-laravel-relationships/#polymorphicManyToManyMorphedByMany

Comment: Thnx I guess you have to dig in Laravel documentation to find out those treats!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working... Basically it's polymorphism + many to many relationship combined. I thought it don't require tags table. Taggables table acts as pivot table and tags is the table which contains Tag objects that connect models based on pivot table (taggables table)

Answer (score 0):

Morphing does not Support Many To Many, it is actually a **one to one association**, it is used to create relations between different Models, so for example if you have Tag Model, the tag model could relate to many different occasions, it could relate to Page Model, to Post Model, to Product Model etc, what it actually achieves is that it allows you to relate to that other model without explicity defining the related model in the DB level, for instance a Tag model could be associated with a Post Model, but then you would need to define in the db, a post_id foreign key, with Polymorphic relations you can relate to that Post Model, without defining the model on the DB level as a specific field:

> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model, on a single association

And in Django Documentation you can clearly see how this association works:

```
staff
    id - integer
    name - string

orders
    id - integer
    price - integer

photos
    id - integer
    path - string
    imageable_id - integer
    imageable_type - string
```

The association from above is: 1 Photo relates to 1 Other Model, **but with a different concrete implementation*** thus a photo can belong to Staff, or it can belong to an order.

Comment: There is many-to-many polymorphic implementation in laravel. http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/visualizing-laravel-relationships/#polymorphicManyToManyMorphedByMany .

The problem is, I have a large number of models that need to be related in many-to-many relationship. It would be inefficient if I just use many-to-many relationship for every two models.

Comment: are you running 4.1 or 4.0?

Comment: laravel 4.1 definitely. It's not available in 4.0

Comment: Finally got it working... Basically it's polymorphism + many to many relationship combined. I thought it don't require tags table. Taggables table acts as pivot table and tags is the table which contains Tag objects that connect models based on pivot table (taggables table).

Comment: Make it an answer to this question :)

Comment: OK, but it's kind of funny that I answer my own question. lol