# Many to Many Eloquent Relation

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, many-to-many, eloquent

I am trying to create a many to many relationship using Laravel 4.1 and Eloquent model. I have 3 tables - songs, artists and song_artist:

```
---- songs 
        -- id
        -- title
        -- genre

---- artists
        - id
        - name

---- song_artist
        - id
        - song_id
        - artist_id
```

Since each song can have multiple artists and each artist can have multiple songs, I assumed I would need to use the `morphToMany()` method instead of the `hasMany()` or `hasManyThrough()` methods.

How would I set up the relation so that I could access the artists related to a song by `$song->artists()`, as well as access the songs related to an aritst by using `$artist->songs()`?

I've already looked into other questions on SO such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435729/laravel-many-to-many-relation), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911579/polymorphic-many-to-many-relation) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198285/many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `song_artist` to `artist_song`, then use [`belongsToMany`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).

If you don't want to rename your table, set it manually:

```
// In Artist
return $this->belongsToMany('Song', 'song_artist');

// In Song
return $this->belongsToMany('Artist', 'song_artist');
```